# Shikakui Hebi: Similarities

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Introduction puzzle: [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106035/shikakui-hebi-introduction)

So, my first Shikakui Hebi puzzle didn't go well, so I'm trying again! Only this time, no more arrows. Instead, it's now a nonogram-like!

This is a Shikakui Hebi puzzle. Rules of Shikakui Hebi are:

- Solvers are to draw 1 big snake/a long line with twists and turns around a rectangular grid.
- The snake is not allowed to form a loop, which means the edges of the snake cannot connect.
- The snake always starts in the lower right corner.
- The snake MUST NOT cross through shaded squares.
- The snake MUST cross through circles.

**New rules:**

- Outer numbers mean that there are that many squares that contain the piece of the snake.
- If the numbers say 1 3, then it means that there is at least 1 empty square between the 1 square and the 3 squares.

Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the solution is unique? I can see the snake can be in many different positions, each makes a same solution.

Comment: I checked, and the outer numbers make the solution unique. In fact, I would be happy if you tell me the other solutions in an answer so I can fix them.

Comment: Look, being the puzzle like a nonogram, I can see no importance of the circles. Solving the nonogram directly gives you the path. Is there any relationship I am missing with the circles?

Comment: The nonogram means that a piece of the snake is in that place, not the direction it's facing. The circles are supposed to help with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions, the puzzle is not unique. I am only showing 2 of them.

Solution 1:-

> [image]

Solution 2:-

> [image]

Comment: Yikes, ok, I didn't expect that

Comment: Also, a note. You got downvotes probably because for this reason that the solution is not unique.

Comment: I missed that, sorry